# why does tex4ht not rotate images?

Tags: graphics, tex4ht

This MWE works ok with `lualatex`

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[angle=90]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

The image is rotated by 90 degrees

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By `make4ht` does not rotate it

```
make4ht foo.tex
```

The HTML shows the image as is.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What does one have to do to make `tex4ht` rotate the image? These images are part of TeXLive 2017.

```
ls /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image.*
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image.eps
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image.jpg
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image.pdf
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image.png
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image.tex
```

**Update**

Found the error. Problem fixed.

What I need is to keep the `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.svg,.png,.eps,.jpg}` but remove the `\Configure{graphics*}`

To make it clear, here is the final .cfg

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.svg,.png,.eps,.jpg}

\makeatletter
\Configure{GraphicsAlt}{ALT\ifdefined\Grot@angle\Css{img[src="\PictureFile"]{transform: rotate(-\Grot@angle deg);}}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

And now `make4ht -c ./nma.cfg foo.tex` finds `p1.svg` and also rotates it.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,angle=130]{p1}  %SVG image

\end{document}
```

Thank to michal.h21 for his help and support.

Comment: you could always just rotate the svg and and then include the rotated image then neither latex nor tex4ht need rotate

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes. I do that now for those images I want to rotate. But it will nice to eliminate this manual step and do it in the code. Also, if I later want to rotate it back, I have to manually do it again.

Comment: you don't need the configurations for `\Configure{graphics*}` in your config file anymore, SVG support is included in tex4ht. I can get the rotated SVG image with my configuration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tex4ht` indeed doesn't support the image rotation, but the support can be added using some hacks. Try the following config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
\Configure{GraphicsAlt}{ALT\ifdefined\Grot@angle\Css{img[src="\PictureFile"]{transform: rotate(-\Grot@angle deg);}}\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

I used the fact that the `GraphicsAlt` configuration is called for every image type, so we need to provide it only once. The `\Grot@angle` macro contains the requested angle. We can provide a CSS declaration for the current picture when it is defined. Your example will produce following CSS code:

```
img[src="sample0x.png"]{transform: rotate(-90deg);}
```

It will be rendered in this way (together with two more samples):

[image]

As you can see the rotated pictures are cropped, which is not good and it is a reason why I don't want to add this feature to `tex4ht` at the moment. If anybody knows how to rotate the images correctly using CSS, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks. But this did not work in my main makefile. After looking on into it, I found why. Will add this information to my main question at the bottom as an update to make it more clear now.